# Unable to Get Data from Github Api in Grails App

Tags: github, grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to make an http request to Github Api in Grails Controller.
I just started learning Grails yesterday and I'm stuck. I searched over internet for hours but it seems there is very little discussion about Grails on internet.
I simply want to call the Github Api and get user Data. I am familiar with the Api Endpoint, I have used it with other frameworks. But I am unable to figure out this (maybe) tiny problem in Grails.
Can anybody help me how do we make API calls in Grails controller?

Thanks in advance and Apologies for a naïve question.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to call an API from a Grails app.  If you are having any particular problem and can articulate that, specific answers can probably be offered up.  Some relevant information is available at https://guides.grails.org/grails-micronaut-http/guide/index.html.

Comment: "But I am unable to figure out this (maybe) tiny problem in Grails." - Can you describe what you tried and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to Get Data from Github Api in Grails App

See the project at [github.com/jeffbrown/tauseefahmedgithubapi](https://github.com/jeffbrown/tauseefahmedgithubapi).

[src/main/groovy/tauseefahmedgithubapi/GitHubClient.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/tauseefahmedgithubapi/blob/f6f3c73729e54bc292d34314ce25acdb97493bef/src/main/groovy/tauseefahmedgithubapi/GitHubClient.groovy)

```
package tauseefahmedgithubapi

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Header
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client

import static io.micronaut.http.HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT

@Client('https://api.github.com/')
interface GitHubClient {

    @Get('/orgs/{org}/repos')
    @Header(name = USER_AGENT, value = 'Micronaut Demo Application')
    List<GitHubRepository> listRepositoriesForOrginazation(String org)
}
```

[src/main/groovy/tauseefahmedgithubapi/GitHubRepository.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/tauseefahmedgithubapi/blob/f6f3c73729e54bc292d34314ce25acdb97493bef/src/main/groovy/tauseefahmedgithubapi/GitHubRepository.groovy)

```
package tauseefahmedgithubapi

import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected

@Introspected
class GitHubRepository {
    String name
}
```

[grails-app/init/tauseefahmedgithubapi/BootStrap.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/tauseefahmedgithubapi/blob/e15ce249209eb71f068e018093de3e141a773d80/grails-app/init/tauseefahmedgithubapi/BootStrap.groovy)

```
package tauseefahmedgithubapi


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

class BootStrap {

    @Autowired
    GitHubClient client

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def repos = client.listRepositoriesForOrginazation('micronaut-projects')
        for(def repo : repos) {
            log.info "Repo Name: ${repo.name}"
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

At application startup you may see output like this:

```
2021-06-28 13:03:16.834  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: static-website
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: presentations
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-core
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-profiles
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-guides-old
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-examples
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: static-website-test
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-docs
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-test
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-kotlin
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-spring
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-oauth2
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-liquibase
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-flyway
2021-06-28 13:03:16.836  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-elasticsearch
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-graphql
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-grpc
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-kafka
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-netflix
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-groovy
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-micrometer
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-sql
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-mongodb
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-redis
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-neo4j
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-rabbitmq
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-aws
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-rss
2021-06-28 13:03:16.837  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-gcp
2021-06-28 13:03:16.838  INFO --- [  restartedMain] tauseefahmedgithubapi.BootStrap          : Repo Name: micronaut-kubernetes
```